# Which sounds in history would you like to have been able to record?

Tags: field-recording, sound-effects-recording

I will suggest;

- The big bang
- Jesus' sermon on the mount
- The vocal sounds of a T Rex
- A big meteor event
- A medieval pitched battle
- E A Poe reading The Raven
- Christmas day truce football match in 1914 France
- Caesar's assasination
- Nelson's last words
- Neanderthals sitting around a fire

Comment: I realise my 1st two suggestions are a little contradictory, but at least one of them probably happened.


Comment: I'd like to record to the future.

Comment: Me too, recording the first meeting of humans & extra terrestrial intelligence would be cool

Comment: @Haydn, your first two suggestions are NOT contradictory. Indeed, you cannot have 1 without 2.

Comment: @JayJennings srsly?

Comment: Food for thought... did the Big Bang make any sound at all?  there was no universe (medium) for any sound to travel through? :)

Answer (score 9):

Besides the obvious answer of extinct animals. My first priority would probably be to record ambiences without the presence of human civilization. No cars and traffic, no aircraft, no electrical interference from cellular and radio...just pristine nature.

Comment: I'm a sucker for recording ambiences, and I fully endorse this answer.

Comment: Me too, the would be a dream come true!

Comment: This could be the closest you get http://onesquareinch.org/about/ I'd love to go there. 

Answer (score 3):

bird life in New Zealand before any humans arrived.... esp the extinct Moa and Huia

Answer (score 2):

Krakatoa probably!

Comment: If it doesn't blow the mic diaphragm first ;)

Comment: Yeah, that may end up being an issue... haha

Answer (score 2):

definitely unspoilt nature sounds!

• Dinosaurs
• The Blitz / DD landings
• Hiroshima
• Alcatraz when full

and as I'm quite young, I feel I missed out on Concord :(

Answer (score 2):

My children growing up......I have a few bit and pieces, but I now wish I'd recored them more regularly, say once a month.  Clique, but they grow up so fast and before you know it you have missed key bits of their development.

Answer (score 1):

Would also be fascinating to record church organs, and baroque ensembles etc. See just how they would have sounded. Maybe our understanding of old sacred music is completely wrong!?

Answer (score 0):

Civil War BAttlefield

Answer (score 0):

people speaking English several centuries ago